# Add nav menu to separate site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm attempting to "weave" two websites together. I know that this is not ideal.

In wordpress there are options to add additional navigation menus but the settings are always for adding existing pages within the CMS. I'd like to add pages to an external site and have them appear as a menu.

Without editing the code, does anyone know of a means to add a custom navigation menu with links to an external site?

Comment: Look at [This Image](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/c/ca/appearance-menus.png). You can do this using the Custom Links option after creating the menu.

Comment: @maiorano84 thanks that looked like it might be helpful but in this version of WP, the latest version, there is no option to add custom links from the left hand side

Comment: No, it's there. The Custom Links Option was never removed. If you're having trouble seeing it, go to Appearance->Menus, and then select Screen Options in the upper-right hand corner. Tick the Custom Links checkbox.

Comment: Yup, that was it, cheers!